# Why does remove() not remove the value specified?

Tags: list, python-2.7

```
list = ['02', '03', '04', '05', '06', 'Inactive', 'Inactive', 'Inactive', 'Inactive', 'Inactive']

list.remove('Inactive')

print list
```

But it just leaves the result unchanged. What did I miss out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It removed the first occurrence of `Inactive` as the [documentation of list `remove` method](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) says. To remove all occurrence, use loop/method/lambda/LC. For example:

```
myList = ['02', '03', '04', '05', '06', 'Inactive', 'Inactive', 'Inactive', 'Inactive', 'Inactive']
removedList = [x for x in myList if x!='Inactive'] # original list unchanged    
# or
removedList = filter(lambda x: x!='Inactive', myList) #leaves original list intact
```

btw, do not use `list` as a variable name

Comment: Oh yes, I changed it to the following on your prompting: for position, item in enumerate(list): list.remove('Inactive') and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list = ['02', '03', '04', '05', '06', 'Inactive', 'Inactive', 'Inactive', 'Inactive', 'Inactive']
>>> list.remove('Inactive')
>>> print list
['02', '03', '04', '05', '06', 'Inactive', 'Inactive', 'Inactive', 'Inactive']
```

It removed one `'Inactive'` for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
for position, item in enumerate(list):
    list.remove('Inactive')
```

This would solve the problem.

Comment: No, that won't work.  It only works in your particular case by fluke because of the numbers involved.  For example, try `my_list = ['2']` (no `Inactive`), which will `ValueError`, or `my_list = ['2', 'Inactive', 'Inactive', 'Inactive']`, which will leave one `Inactive` there.